# Append event to an already existing event in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an already defined click event attacked to a link and I was wondering what's the best way to **APPEND** (**NOT OVERWRITE**) another click event to this event in pure javascript.

Here is my code([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9q6aLtf/)):

```
var link = document.getElementById('click');
link.onclick = function(){
    alert("1st click");
};
link.onclick = function(){
    alert("2nd click");
};
```

The above code overwrites the first onclick event.

Additionally, I know that this is possible(without overwriting) in jQuery with this code([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nghvuL6s/)):

```
var link = $('#click');
link.click(function(){
    alert("1st click");
});
link.click(function(){
    alert("2nd click");
});
```

I just want the same in vanilla Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: There's actually no problem... I just found the answer when I was asking this question and just wanted to share with other people that may have some doubt/problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Handling events with event listeners is the right way([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8xmo9bv/)):

```
var link = document.getElementById('click');
link.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("1st click");
});
link.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("2nd click");
});
```